# Fix the format of the retrieved data from the database using wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am retrieving data from database for multiple rows using the `get_result()` function in wordpress.

I am able to retrieve the required data but the format is wrong - how can I fix it?

```
Array ([0] => stdClass Object ( [siteNAME] => test0 )
```

I need the format to be:

```
test0, test1, test2
```

Code:

```
$result2 = $wpdb->get_results('select siteNAME from `site_info` where ownerID=159' );

print_r($result2);
```

Comment: Add foreach loop after your result so it will give you object of all results after that explode each result with comma separated so it will give you exact result as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 'echo' instead of 'print_r'.

With 'ownerID', check this code:

```
$result2 = $wpdb->get_results('select siteNAME from `site_info` where ownerID=159' );
foreach($result2 as $result) {
   echo $result->siteNAME;
}
```

OR

Without 'ownerID', check this code:

```
$result2 = $wpdb->get_results('select siteNAME from `site_info` ');
foreach($result2 as $result) {
    echo $result->siteNAME;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

print_r() function is mainly used for printing arrays.

Hope, this may be helpful for you.

Comment: your answer did not work as i was hoping it display **stdClass Object ( [siteNAME] =>**   when i use echo it return an error **object of class stdclass could not be converted to string**